# Find out instance variable name out of itself

Tags: javascript, oop, function

I've created a JavaScript Class just as following:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.myProp = '';
}
MyClass.prototype.myTestFunction = function() {
    alert('test');
}
```

Now, I instantiate this class.

```
var myTestInstance = new MyClass();
myTestInstance.myTestFunction();
```

This outputs an alert with 'test'.

Now I want to have the variable name 'myTestInstance' into the function 'myTestFunction()' without having to pass it as a parameter.

Is it somehow possible to find out the variable name of the instance from inside the called function?

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: Just to add information why I would need this: Every instance I create in my real project is a special HTML table. In the header fields are sort-buttons for every column. Therefore I added dynamically a link-element with `href='javascript:myTableInstance.sort()'`. To print this dynamically IN the instance, I needed the variable name.

Would there be another, better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not make sense in any way. First of all, instance is not tied to a single variable (it might be referenced by many variables, it could be referenced by none - perhaps as a member of some array) - so the question "what is the name of the variable that stores the instance" is unanswerable. Secondly, the scope of myTestFunction and myTestInstance could be very different. In a usual case myTestFunction would not "see" the scope that has myTestInstance defined - so knowing the name of the variable would not help.

You should just use "this" inside myTestFunction.